# Active Directory Delegated AD Admins editing properties of users

Tags: active-directory

I have delegated some (non-admin) users as admins for several OUs, however they are unable to edit their own properties or those of other delegated admins. I chose these settings for each user:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: By "unable to edit" I assume you mean that "Access Denied" errors are being received. I'd be interested in seeing a picture of the Access Control List on a user object that you're seeing this behavior with. (I have an adminSDHolder kind of feeling today...)

Comment: The users are probably a part of a protected group (admincount attrib = 1) and not subject to inherited permissions from the delegation.  So check and see if these accounts in question have this attribute set.  You can use `Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(objectcategory=person)(samaccountname=*)(admincount=1)"` to figure this out

Comment: @Evan Anderson I am not getting any errors, I just can't edit any fields in another delegated admin's Organization Tab: [link](http://i.imgur.com/ZexNPLn.png) when logged in with a delegated admin account.

Comment: Are the fields editable or are they grayed out? Do the user accounts exist in the delegated OU's?

Comment: @joeqwerty They are not editable and some are greyed out. Those users are in an OU of which they are delegated admins

Comment: @TheCleaner I tried that command but did not return anything

Comment: @TheCleaner Sorry there was a typo in the command. Those users are returned when I substitute * for their accountname.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user accounts have been put into a protected group and have their `adminCount` property set to 1. This prevents the user accounts from inheriting permissions from their parent container. This is preventing your inheritance from working.

You can reset the `adminCount` property to 0 on these accounts and re-enable inheritance, but if they're members of any protected groups ("Domain Admins", etc) it will be reset and inheritance will be blocked again.

You can learn more about this feature from: [AdminSDHolder, Protected Groups and SDPROP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.09.sdadminholder.aspx)

Comment: I see, so because they have been added to Delegated AD Admins group, their adminCount property was set to 1. I as a Domain Admin can edit their properties. I guess this is the only workaround?

Comment: Becuause they were at one time added to a protected group (as described in the article I linked) their `adminCount` property has been set to 1 and `SDPROP` is removing their inheritance and setting their permissions explicitly. If these user are removed from any protected groups and have their `adminCount` set back to `0` you can re-enable inheritance and they'll act just like other "normal" users.

Comment: You can also exclude groups from AdminSDHolder's icy grasp: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.09.sdadminholder.aspx

Comment: hrmmm...to upvote or not. ;)  --btw you could also in essence check the "inherit permissions" box on each of these accounts (en mass) and then run the delegation wizard again.  The accounts should get the delegation inheritance and then the adminSDHolder will automatically uncheck the box after it cycles again.  EDIT: as the link from @RyanRies points out basically in the call out window